# How to validate a name in C without using isalpha?

Tags: c, validation

I'm a beginner in C programming, and I want to validate the name the user has input without using isalpha. Is that possible?

```
char name[51];

puts("Please enter your name");
scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
```

Comment: Validate in respect to what?

Comment: Also, don't expect people to write your code for you if you don't show a little effort to try and solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Validate in respect to alphabets.
I did try to solve this problem by doing research on the net and trying out the solutions but I don't really understand the isalpha and the strlen used by other people, that's why I resorted to asking it here.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - It's very clear from the question that the user has to replicate the validation provided by `isalpha` function, but without using it.

Comment: You should probably put a little time into trying to understand isalpha and strlen used by other people.  I think you're asking for trouble if your approach is "I don't understand what other people have done so I want to do something different".  isalpha() is a one line function...

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` does not attempt to validate input.  Instead it prevents certain input.  Using this approach code does not handle invalid input.  Instead it remains in `stdin` - unread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please modify your code as shown below and see if it works.

```
char name[51];
puts("Please enter your name");
if (scanf(" %50[a-zA-Z]", name) == 1) {
    printf("Name : %s",name);
}else{
    printf("Error: Invalid input!");
}
```

The above code should read a maximum of 50 characters from the provided character set i.e lowercase and uppercase alphabets.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you for the solution and the explanation! I understand it clearly =)

Comment: What is code trying to accomplish with `"c\n"`?  Note that if input is only `"\n"`, `name[]` is not altered.

Comment: To fix both problems indicated by chux, use this: `if (scanf(" %50[a-zA-Z]", name) == 1) { /* name was read */ }`. Note however that both `O'Neil` and `Mister-T` will be mishandled.

Comment: @chqrlie - I've edited my answer based on your inputs.

Comment: @Beginner: yes, it looks better now, but in case of invalid input, the offending characters are left pending in the input stream.  An alternate approach with `fgets()` + `sscanf()` allows better control and easier handling of input errors.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is already an accepted answer, I think that you may still need clarification about how to go about solving a problem like this (without copying someone's solution).

A string is an array of characters ending with a null terminator ('\0' character). Knowing this, after you get the user input string, you can just loop over the string until you reach the '\0' character, and test each character for valid letters.

You can use cascading if-statements to test for the presence of a letter, or you could use a switch-statement which would be far more efficient (this is a good opportunity to learn about how switch statements differ from cascading if-statements, hint: switch is really just computed goto), or use an alphabet string that you loop over (I still prefer the switch-statement because of efficiency). If anything other than a letter (as specified in your switch-statement) is present, then just print an error message and return from the function with an error code.

If you are testing for multiple words that are separated by whitespace like spaces, tabs, or newlines, then just include that in the switch statement as special conditions.